# move_uploaded_file permission denied / changing upload_tmp_directory

Tags: php, file-upload, ubuntu-16.04

I've done this before on shared servers, but this is not working with my dedicated server. Basically, I am trying to upload some image files with a simple php script. As the title suggests though, I am getting an error when I try to move the files with `move_uploaded_file()`, and of course the rest of the application fails because I have no images to process - I'm pretty sure the images never make it to the temporary directory because the permissions won't allow it.

Anyway, I have been trying to change the tmp directory to some other directory where there should be appropriate permissions by editing the php.ini file, but after dozens of attempts I still see "/tmp" (the default) when I echo `sys_get_temp_dir()`. I have added this line to php.ini: `upload_tmp_dir ="/var/www/uploads"`. I cannot figure out if the path is incomplete or incorrect (the "uploads" directory does exist). I have tried other variations of this, but I just cannot figure out why it's not changing.

Comment: Do a `file_exists` on your tmp file, and make sure it's being created. Next: Make sure you have permissions on the folder you're trying to move it to (That's most likely the cause). Enable error reporting, and be sure you're outputting errors on screen.

Comment: try to add a slash after the uploads .. like upload_tmp_dir="/var/www/uploads/"

Comment: Thanks FrankerZ. I cannot see any tmp files in the current tmp directory, and I'm sure I have not set up permissions for the "www-data" user. However, I am just trying to point to another directory where the user does have permissions, but my php.ini edits are just not sticking.